# Given the melody, can the chords be determined?

Tags: chords

Here is a sample melody - this was given as an exercise for sight-reading, etc. Anyways, so the chords were added in later: I removed them for this question. (This is not HW!)

My question is, can the chords be guessed and where they should go?

I am aware that a melody is able to be determined given chords (this is done on AP exam)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Of course you can. Except that for an experienced composer there is no "guessing" involved, and also there isn't usually  a single "right answer". Of course this song is so well known that many musicians would just write down the usual chords by "hearing the recorded version in their head" - not by guessing or experimenting on an instrument! (As I've said several times before here, the most important thing to learn about music theory is how to "see with your ears, and hear with your eyes.")

Comment: suppose I did not know the original tune? (i've actually never heard it before this exercise) would I be able to 'figure it out?'

Comment: I can clearly read that the titles of your sheets are "Puff the Magic Dragon", and at any rate, I recognize that tune. I think that will rig the answers on this site.

Comment: Why should it? While there is actually only one original chord sequence it doesn't equate to the best, only an alternative. If the sequence had been different but still apposite, then someone came up with the same as the original actually is, would that be deemed better, worse, or what? That's actually not the thrust the OP wanted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Safe way with simple (3 or 4) notes per bar is to take those notes and fit any chords which contain them into that bar. Granted not always possible, but taking that second bar as B and G, Em or G are prime suspects, and either will do technically, although what follows may make one sound better than another. Unless you are looking to follow the original harmony, which others you may play with will probably know, this method works, especially using notes on beats one and three as guides.

Answer (score 7):

Generally, yes! That's how I compose most of my music, actually, by first creating a melody and then adding chords that fit it. The best part is, there isn't *technically* a right or wrong answer (well, let's be honest: if you're trying to determine chords from a melody of an existing song, the original chords are the right answer) when you're composing—whatever works, works!

Comment: that makes sense: some people just do improvisation/remixing. However try to keep the original chords as close as possible.

Comment: What on Earth are "the original chords" of, say, a folk song like "O Christmas Tree"? Just because the song exists and everybody knows it doesn't mean we know "the original chords" with 100% accuracy, and let's just say that the Vince Guaraldi harmonization of that song is pretty different from mine.

Comment: @Dekkadeci - good point , there are many songs that to me benefit from reharmonisation. Summertime, Over the Rainbow are a couple ripe for it!

Comment: OH reharmonization!

Comment: It's a pity that so many people know 'Summertime' and 'Rainbow' from versions where a modern singer paraphrases the melody in an over-emotional way over a strummed guitar.  Particularly with 'Summertime' go to the source before deciding you can do something better.

Answer (score 7):

Chords cannot be DETERMINED from a melody, or melody from chords.  But we can do a lot better than guessing!  It may be that a melody strongly suggests a certain, simple harmony.  But variations will almost always be possible.  You could amuse yourself by working out several alternative harmonisations of 'Puff'.  It isn't hard, and doesn't have to involve going self-consciously 'far out'.  Though, of course, the standard harmonisation of 'Puff' is so well-known that a variant may be heard as merely annoyingly quirky.